# Did they remove the player statistics in Beat Saber?

Tags: beat-saber

Beat Saber recently got a major UI overhaul. The menus and the navigation looks completely different and now I can't find my personal stats (They showed things like actual playtime, wins, average grade etc...).

Did they remove the statistics or did I just miss them?

ps: I'm on PC and just updated today (11/14/20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On October 13, 2020 with the release of version v1.12.1 the player statistics were removed.

From the release notes:

> - Player statistics pane temporarily removed

On January 21, 2021 version v1.13.2 was released which brought the player statistics back

From the release notes:

> - Brought back Player Statistics (including Online stats) into Help/How to Play screen.